# SetEnv inherit from Host htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

With my htaccess file, I'm setting this environment variable

```
SetEnv CI_ENV development
```

But I actually want to inherit the environment variable from the host. Something like

```
SetEnv CI_ENV %{CI_ENV}
```

I've tried:

```
SetEnv CI_ENV %{ENV:CI_ENV}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Reason: I'm using docker with a PHP/Apache container. Trying to pass configuration value into it so I'd like to not have anything hardcoded in the htaccess file if possible.

My current workaround is to have a .htaccess.config file with $CI_ENV in the file, and then using a script to substitute the env values, but would be nice to not have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redeclare env variables if you use `mod_setevif`.

Use this directive in your root .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ CI_ENV=development
```

Then use it anywhere in sub-directories without any need of re-delcaring it.

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below, it seems OP is trying to pass system (shell) env variables to Apache.

For that `PassEnv` directive can be used like this:

```
# pass system env CI_ENV to Apache
PassEnv CI_ENV
```

Now `CI_ENV` will be available as env variables in various Apache directives.

Comment: So the CI_ENV is set on the host linux machine. I'm trying not to have variables hardcoded in the htaccess file

Comment: So maybe I'm confused on what SetEnvIf actually does. Basically I have env variables already defined on the machine that started apache but they aren't accepted in my PHP scripts unless they are declared via SetEnv... So I'm just trying to pass those values in (I don't want to have to type into any config "development" if that makes sense)

Comment: Env variables defined in shell are different from Apache env variables. Apache env variables are defined in Apache config files or in .htaccess via various Apache directives e,g, `mos_setenvif`, `mod_rewrite` etc.

Comment: i realize that - hence why I opened up this ticket :-) trying to find a way for it to grab env variables defined from shell that executed apache :-)

Comment: Check my edited answer. Most likely `PassEnv` will work for you.